# Tracking down an old book (pre-1970) about Intelligent Plant life

Tags: story-identification

I'm looking for a short story that I read in the 1960's as a teenager. The plot was about planetary exploration. The hero finds intelligent plant life that has all of the answers to man's questions. The only exception is when Man is too stupid to comprehend and then the plant replies "You don't have the words". The twist is that the conversation is simply a web to entrap the questioner who's transformed into a soporific state and then consumed.

Comment: In the title of your question you said it's a **book**, but in the body of the question it's a **short story**. I'm guessing it's a short story, am I right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Stanley Weinbaum's [The Lotus Eaters](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?47500) concerns explorers who encounter incredibly intelligent plants, so intelligent that they can deduce the nature of an entire universe given a single fact about it.The plants emit narcotic spores which put the explorers in peril, although the immediate danger is from other creatures attacking the soporific explorers, not the plants themselves.

There is an exchange with one of the plants (nicknamed "Oscar") which is very reminiscent of this part of your question:

*The hero finds intelligent plant life that has all of the answers to
man's questions. The only exception is when Man is too stupid to
comprehend and then the plant replies "You don't have the words".*

---

> Both listeners stared in awe at the creature.  "Say!" gulped Ham. "If
> that's true we could find out anything from Oscar! Oscar, can you tell
> us secrets we don't know?"
>
> "No."
>
> "Why not?"
>
> "You must first have the words to give me.  I cannot tell you that for
> which you have no words."

---

It has been anthologized often so it was definitely available in the 60s.

Comment: Thank you OM. That's the one I was thinking of. There are a couple of other stories that have stuck in my mind which I'll be adding to the list in the next few days.